# Ionic live reload change host

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic7

I have an Ionic capacitor react app.
Would like to have live reload to use localhost instead of IP address.

i have some Content Security Policy  restrictions that app runs only on localhost

tried
`ionic cap run android -l --external --port=3000 --host=localhost`
but this is not working.

using ionic 7